# Learning similarity of representations

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recommender-system, word2vec

I am interested in a framework for mapping together input representations based on some common context. I have looked into word2vec, which does more or less what I want, but I want to know if anyone here has any experience or resources on a more generalized version of this.

For example: 
Say we have some customers we are sending different advertisements to, and I would like to create a system to map offers to customers. I am thinking in the lines of creating a customer representation, and a representation of the offers, and feeding them in parallel to a neural network that has a label of whether they acted on the advertisement or not. The idea is that I should be able to locate the best offer for any customer given these representations.

I have looked into siamese networks and word2vec, both are close to what I want. The problem differs slightly in that the for the siamese networks, there are identical parallel networks, which I don't want because my inputs are not equivalent. Word2vec type methodology is also close, but I would want a model to process the inputs on "both sides". A combination of the two, is kind of what I am looking for.

If anyone has any resources on a similar problem statement, I would be very interested in it.

Thanks

Comment: It almost sounds like you're looking for the left- and right-eigenvectors produced by SVD. A matrix composed of users (rows) by advertisements (columns) can be factored into matrices that project users into one matrix and advertisements into another matrix. This approach doesn't include information about labels, however, but SVD certainly seems like this is in the same thematic category as what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Yes SVD is also in the same category and could be an option for my problem. But as I understand, SVD create the representations from the "interaction"-matrix. I want to create the initial representations myself, and then learn a mapping based on them together with the labels indicating a connection or not. I am not sure if it is possible to adapt SVD to do something like this?

Comment: Well, SVD always produces a factorization in the same way. If you want to start with hand-crafted representations, I suppose SVD is not the right solution.